# Retrieving value from Tkinter Entry box

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to get Tkinter to return the value from the input box, but I cannot seem to get it to work.

This is my first attempt trying Tkinter out, s

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "n:\regnskab\Afregning\RIK\Udvikling\gui\app2.py", line 43, in step_1
    periode_2 = get_period(self)
NameError: name 'get_period' is not defined
```

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Mainframe(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kvargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kvargs)


        self.title("app")

        UserInputFrame(self).grid(row=1, column=0)
        ControlsFrame(self).grid(row=2, column=0)
        ButtonFrame(self).grid(row=3, column=0)


class UserInputFrame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container):
        super().__init__(container)

        self.user_input_year = tk.StringVar(value="2021")

        label_entry_year = ttk.Label(self, text="Year")
        self.entry_year = ttk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.user_input_year)

        label_entry_year.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="W", padx=10, pady=5)
        self.entry_year.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="EW")

    def get_period(self):
        print(self.entry_year.get())



class ControlsFrame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container):
        super().__init__(container)

        step_1_button = ttk.Button(self, text="Step 1", command=self.step_1)


        step_1_button.grid(row=10, column=0, sticky="EW")

    def step_1(self):
        periode_2 = get_period(self)
        print("step 1")



class ButtonFrame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container):
        super().__init__(container)

        quit_button = ttk.Button(self, text="Quit", command=quit)
        quit_button.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky="EW")


    def quit(self):
        app.destroy


app = Mainframe()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: you have to learn `OOP`. `get_period` is not standalone function but function inside class `UserInputFrame` - so you would have to get instance of `UserInputFrame`, send it as argument to `ControlsFrame` and then use `instance_of_control_frame.get_period()` You can't access in one class function from other class.

Answer (score 1):

You have to learn OOP :)

`get_period()` is not standalone function but it is function inside class `UserInputFrame` and you try to access it in class `ControlsFrame`. You can't access function for one class in other class this way.

You would have to get instance of `UserInputFrame`,

```
    user_input_frame = UserInputFrame(self)
    user_input_frame.grid(row=1, column=0)
```

send it as argument to `ControlsFrame`

```
    ControlsFrame(self, user_input_frame).grid(row=2, column=0)
```

keep it in class variable

```
class ControlsFrame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container, user_input_frame):
        super().__init__(container)

        self.user_input_frame = user_input_frame
```

and then you can use it

```
def step_1(self):
    self.user_input_frame.get_period()  # without `self` in `get_period()`
```

---

OR better method

You should assing `UserInputFrame` to class variable in `Mainframe`

```
self.user_input_frame = UserInputFrame(self)
self.user_input_frame.grid(row=1, column=0)
```

and then other objects (created in `Mainframe`) may access `Mainframe` (which is its paret/master) using `self.master` and then they can access elements in `Mainframe` like `self.master.userinputframe`

```
periode_2 = self.master.user_input_frame.get_period() # without `self` in `get_period()`
```

---

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Mainframe(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kvargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kvargs)

        self.title("app")

        self.user_input_frame = UserInputFrame(self)
        self.user_input_frame.grid(row=1, column=0)

        ControlsFrame(self).grid(row=2, column=0)
        ButtonFrame(self).grid(row=3, column=0)


class UserInputFrame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container):
        super().__init__(container)

        self.user_input_year = tk.StringVar(value="2021")

        label_entry_year = ttk.Label(self, text="Year")
        self.entry_year = ttk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.user_input_year)

        label_entry_year.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="W", padx=10, pady=5)
        self.entry_year.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="EW")

    def get_period(self):
        #print(self.entry_year.get())
        return self.entry_year.get()



class ControlsFrame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container):
        super().__init__(container)

        step_1_button = ttk.Button(self, text="Step 1", command=self.step_1)
        step_1_button.grid(row=10, column=0, sticky="EW")

    def step_1(self):
        # `self.master` gives access to parent object which here is `Masterframe` (because you used `Masterframe` as `self` when you created `ControlsFrame(self)`
        periode_2 = self.master.user_input_frame.get_period() # without `self` in `get_period()`
        print("step 1")



class ButtonFrame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container):
        super().__init__(container)

        quit_button = ttk.Button(self, text="Quit", command=self.quit)
        quit_button.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky="EW")

    def quit(self):
        app.destroy()


app = Mainframe()
app.mainloop()
```

---

BTW: in `ButtonFrame` you forgot `self.` in `command=self.quit` and `()` in `app.destroy()`

---

**EDIT:** as @acw1668 noticed function `get_period()` doesn't return value from entry - it only print it - so it needs `return`

```
    def get_period(self):
        return self.entry_year.get()
```

Comment: Please note that `get_period()` return `None`.  Change it to `def get_period(self): return self.entry_year.get()`.

Comment: @acw1668 good point :) I added it to answer

Comment: thanks a lot - got it to work with the second method. Why do you consider this superior to  the first?

Comment: second version is universal - all classes have access to `user_input_frame`. The same way you can access `self.master.user_input_frame` in `ButtonFrame`. If you add another widget in main window then it will also have access to `self.master.user_input_frame`. And similar way you can set `self.control_frame = ControlsFrame(...)`  and other widgets will have access to `control_frame` using `self.master.control_frame`.